# coordinates from kml file arrive modified in emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, gps, emulation, ddms

I have some trouble while sending coordinates form a kml file to my emulator.
For example I'm sending `long: 13,428753` `lat: 52,518823` and I receive: `13.428751666666669`and `52.51882166666666`

When creating markers on a `GoogleMap` with these coordinates I receive a marker with a slightly different position but this breaks comparisons between `LatLng` object. Any ideas how I can fix this? I can provide more information if needed.

How I receive my data:

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {  
        if(CurrentJourney.getInstance().getJourney() == null) {
            return;
        }

        CurrentJourney.getInstance().getJourney().getCoordinates()
            .add(new LatLng (location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

        String latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        String longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_NEW_LOCATION);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NEW_LATITUDE, latitude);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NEW_LONGITUDE, longitude);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Seems like you're using `float` instead of `double` for the coordinates.

Comment: Yeah I already guessed something like this but I don't store the coordinates somewhere as a float. I also added my receiver code